# Regex to match pipes not within brackets or braces

Tags: ruby, regex

I am trying to parse some wiki markup. For example, the following:

```
{{Infobox 
| person
| name = Joe
| title = Ruler
| location = [[United States|USA]] | height = {{convert|12|m|abbr=on}}
| note = <ref>{{cite book|title= Some Book}}</ref>  
}}
```

can be the text to start with. I first remove the starting `{{` and ending `}}`, so I can assume those are gone.

I want to do `.split(<regex>)` on the string to split the string by all `|` characters that are not within braces or brackets. The regex needs to ignore the `|` characters in `[[United States|USA]]`, `{{convert|12|m|abbr=on}}`, and `{{cite book|title= Some Book}}`. The expected result is:

```
[
 'person'
 'name = Joe', 
 'title = Ruler', 
 'location = [[United States|USA]]',
 'height = {{convert|12|m|abbr=on}}',
 'note = <ref>{{cite book|title= Some Book}}</ref>'
]
```

There can be line breaks at any point, so I can't just look for `\n|`.  If there is extra white space in it, that is fine. I can easily strip out extra `\s*` or `\n*`.

Comment: A quick solution would be using `\s*\|\s*(?![^{\[]*[]}])`. See live demo here https://regex101.com/r/dEDcAS/1

Comment: @revo's suggestion looks great, I hope you can remove the `{{` `}}`s *after* splitting, rather than before, else it may be much more difficult

Comment: To write a parser for a markup language, you are likely to need a whole group of regexps that should fit.If we assume you want to match 1 or more word chars that can be followed with an optional sequence of `=`, then 1 or more sequences of `{{...}}` (with no nested `{{...}}`), `[[...]]` (with no nested `[[...]]`) or any char other than `|`, `[` and `{`, you may use `s.scan(/\w+(?:\s*=\s*(?:\[\[[^\]\[]*]]|{{[^{}]*}}|[^|{\[])*)?/)`,see [this demo](http://rubular.com/r/xowHisf1K9).It may be further enhanced, but without  knowing what you run before or after, it is hard to say if it works for you.

Comment: in your example output it looks like you have a new line after `person` but no comma after it.  Also it shows single quotes.  Do you want an array or a string output that looks like an array?

Comment: @revo your solution was actually spot on. If you want to post that as an answer I will gladly give it the check. Worked exactly for what I needed!

Comment: Your expected result is invalid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could split on:

```
\s*\|\s*(?![^{\[]*[]}])
```

Breakdown:

- `\s*\|\s*` Match a pipe with any leading or trailing whitespaces
- `(?!` Start of negative lookahead

  - `[^{\[]*` Match anything except `{` and `[` as much as possible
  - `[]}]` Up to a closing `]` or `}`
- `)` End of negative lookahead

The negative lookahead asserts that we shouldn't reach `}` or `]` without matching an opening pair.

See [live demo here](https://regex101.com/r/dEDcAS/1)

Comment: so this works about 95%. I found a case that doesn't work though and hoping you can help? https://regex101.com/r/dEDcAS/2

Comment: Actually you can't adjust this for nested blocks. You'd better ask another question since that would be totally different.

Comment: Copy that! Much appreciated.

Answer (score -2):

I literally stole the regex from @WiktorStribiżew but this should work for your input string

```
regex = (/\w+(?:\s*=\s*(?:\[\[[^\]\[]*]]|{{[^{}]*}}|[^|{\[])*)?/)
arr = str.scan(regex).map{|l| l.strip.delete("\n")}[1..-1]
```

`arr` is now the array you've requested.

Comment: Did you read last line *...there can be linebreaks at any point so can't just look for `\n|`*?

Comment: This should give the requested result now